# The Identity Theorem for real analytic functions

Tags: real-analysis, analyticity

What is the condition for two real analytic functions to be identically equal? We know that there is a nice condition ([Identity Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_theorem)) for holomorphic function to check if they are the same. What is its version for real analytic functions?

Comment: If $U$ is a domain, and $f,g$ are two real-analytic functions defined on $U$, and if $V\subset U$ is a nonempty open set with $f\lvert_V \equiv g\lvert_V$, then $f \equiv g$. If the domain is one-dimensional (an interval in $\mathbb{R}$), then it suffices that $f\lvert_M \equiv g\lvert_M$ for some $M\subset U$ that has an accumulation point in $U$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks, I also think it should be like this way, but would you give me some references about it?

Comment: Can't list a reference, but it's proved exactly like the holomorphic case. For the nonempty open $V$ case (without loss of generality $g\equiv 0$), you consider the set $W = \{ x : f\lvert_N \equiv 0 \text{ for some neighbourhood } N \text{ of } x\}$, and show $W$ is open (by definition) and closed. For the $M$ has an accumulation point case, consider the power series expansion in the accumulation point, derive all coefficients are $0$, and you're in the first case.

Comment: @DanielFischer Right,thank you.

Comment: @DanielFischer "If U
 is a domain...." ,what does domain mean here ? must U be open and connected ?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

As a reference, I suggest *A Primer of Real Analytic Functions* by Krantz and Parks.

The two versions of the Identity Theorem stated by Daniel Fisher can be unified at the expense of more complicated statement.

> If $U$ is a domain, and $f,g$ are two real-analytic functions defined on $U$, and if $V\subset U$ is a nonempty open set with $f\lvert_V \equiv g\lvert_V$, then $f \equiv g$. If the domain is one-dimensional (an interval in $\mathbb{R}$), then it suffices that $f\lvert_M \equiv g\lvert_M$ for some $M\subset U$ that has an accumulation point in $U$.

**Claim**. *If $f,g$ are real analytic and there is a point $p\in \mathbb R^n$ such that the set of all limits 
$$ \left\{\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{x_n-p}{|x_n-p|} : \qquad f(x_n)=g(x_n),\  x_n\to p, \ x_n\ne p\right\} \tag{1}$$
has an interior point in the topology of  the sphere $S^{n-1}$, then $f\equiv g$.*

Indeed, suppose $f-g$ is not identically zero. Express its Taylor series at $p$ as the sum of homogeneous polynomials $P_d$. Let $d$ be the smallest degree for which $P_d$ is not identically zero. Then the set defined by (1) can be shown to be precisely
$$
S^{n-1} \cap \{ P_d =0\}
\tag{2}$$
Since the zero set of a polynomial has empty interior in $\mathbb R^n$, it follows that (2) has empty interior in $S^{n-1}$. $\quad \Box$

When $n=1$, the sphere $S^0$ is a two-point set, so any nonempty subset of it has nonempty interior. We thus recover the one-dimensional result.

Comment: How to prove the claim?

Comment: @Yui The part beginning with "Indeed" is meant to be a proof, at least in an outline.

Comment: I know this is an old post. But does this conclusion hold in $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: I think there is something wrong with the claim. In $\mathbb{R}^2$ the analytic function $\sin(2\pi (x^2+y^2))$ vanishes on the unit circle. What am I missing?

Comment: @Kosh, the set points where that function vanishes in R^2 has an empty interior. You need this to hold over an entire area in R^2.