# A function property to guarantee that being constant on an interval implies identically constant

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, analyticity

Let $f:\mathbb R\rightarrow \mathbb R$. Suppose we know that $f $ is a constant on some open/closed interval.
Which condition does guarantee that $f $ is constant on $\mathbb R$?

Clearly, continuity is not enough. Differentiable? $C^1$? smooth? real analytic?

Answer (score 1):

Real analytic is enough.

Smooth is not enough. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bump_function

Comment: can u please prove this fact that a real analytic function satisfies the problem posed by  OP

Comment: @learnmore See [The Identity Theorem for real analytic functions](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/739476/the-identity-theorem-for-real-analytic-functions)