# Band-limited function vanishing on a set of positive measure

Tags: analysis, fourier-analysis

I'm working my way through a Fourier analysis textbook and came across the classic result that a function cannot be both band- and time-limited, that is, if both $f$ and $\hat{f}$ are compactly supported then $f \equiv 0$. It also says that in fact if $f$ vanishes on *any* interval and $\hat{f}$ is compactly supported then $f \equiv 0$. My question is: does this result also hold for sets of positive measure, not just intervals?

Answer (score 1):

If the support of $\hat f$ is contained in $[-M,M]$, then 
$$
f(x) = \int_{-M}^M \hat f(\xi)e^{ix \xi }\,d\xi
$$
(ignoring various constants involving $\pi$). Expand the exponential function into a power series. Since the series converges *uniformly* on $[-M,M]$, it can be integrated term by term, resulting in   a uniformly convergent series
$$
f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{i^n x^n}{n!} \int_{-M}^M \hat f(\xi)\xi^n  \,d\xi
$$
Therefore, $f$ is a real-analytic function: it is locally represented by a power series. [The Identity Theorem for real analytic functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/739476/) says that the zero set of $f$ has no points of accumulation. In particular, it is countable, hence of measure zero.

Let me qualify the above statement with: when dealing with Fourier transform, functions that agree up to a null set are indistinguishable. So, the precise statement is that $f$ has a *representative* that is real-analytic. The conclusion about the zero set being of measure zero makes sense since this property is independent of the choice of a representative.