# Does the zeros of an analytic function $f$ form a discrete set?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

A function $f$ is called analytic if locally it is given by a convergent power series.

Let $ U \subset \mathbb R^n $ be an open set and $f : U \to \mathbb R$ be non zero analytic function. Does the zeros of $f$ form a discrete set?

I'm unable to find counterexample.Please help!

Comment: the zeros of analytic complex function are indeed a discrete set. Don't know about $\mathbb R^n$ though :)

Comment: @Ant ofcourse thats true!

Comment: [This](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/739476/the-identity-theorem-for-real-analytic-functions) post on the identity theorem for real-analytic functions is what you're after, I believe.

Comment: You seem to be looking at "real-analytic" functions. On $\Bbb R ^2$ consider the function $f(x,y) = y.$

Comment: @zhw. Thank you.Does the result holds for n=1?

Comment: Sure, and whatever proof you know for holomorphic functions can be used for $n=1.$

Comment: Ohh I see.Thank you.Regards,