# Is a real-analytic function which vanishes on a set of positive measure identically zero?

Tags: real-analysis, analyticity, analytic-functions

Suppose $n>1$, and let $U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ be an open connected set.

Let $f$ be a real-analytic function on $U$. Suppose that $f=0$ on a subset of $U$ of positive measure. Is it true that $f$ vanishes identically?

I know that if $f=0$ on an *open* subset of $U$, then it is identically zero. (This is the [identity theorem for real-analytic functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/739476/the-identity-theorem-for-real-analytic-functions)).