# Does the Taylor series of a real analytic function $f(x)$ converge to $f(x)$ inside the interval of convergence?

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion, analyticity, analytic-functions

Suppose that $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is analytic at $x=0$, and $T(x)$ its Taylor series at $x=0$, with radius of convergence $R>0$. Is it true that $f(x)=T(x)$ whenever $|x|<R$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  For a counterexample, try

$$f(x) = \begin{cases}e^x & \text{ if } x < 1 \\ 0 & \text{ if } x \geq 1\end{cases}$$

Then $R = \infty,$ but $T(x) = e^x \neq f(x)$ for $x > 1.$

Comment: Note that if we assume $f(x)$ is analytic on $|x| < R,$ then the answer becomes "yes," which we can see by e.g. the Lagrange form of the Taylor remainder.

Comment: How does the Lagrange form of the Taylor remainder imply "yes" ?

Comment: Since your function $f$ is *not* analytic, that is not a counterexample.

Comment: @ashpool Is $f$ analytic according to the definition of analytic function that you are working with?

Comment: @Jose Carlos Santos Yes; in my question, I (foolishly) imposed analyticity condition only at $x=0$.

Comment: @ashpool Right! I missed that.

Comment: @ashpool Well, my gut still says that using Taylor's theorem should suffice, but I can't find a proof right now.   In any case, when $f(x)$ is analytic on $|x| < R,$ then JoséCarlosSantos' answer would apply to give us equality on $|x|<R$.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is true. It follows from the definition of analytic function that the equality $f(x)=T(x)$ holds on some interval $(-r,r)$. But then you can use the [identity theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_theorem): since $(-r,r)$ has accumulation points (actually, each of its points is an accumulation point), and since $(-R,R)$ is connected, $f=T$.

Comment: Thanks. But the Wikipedia article you linked seems to say that the identity theorem does not apply to real-valued functions.

Comment: I think I found the answer to my question here (https://math.stackexchange.com/q/739476/4341), and the proof seems highly nontrivial (and not very satisfying).

Comment: The article is written in the context of complex analysis, but, yes, it also [holds for real analytical functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/741084/446262). And the proof is exactly the same as in the context of complex analytical functions.

Comment: José, would you check if my answer is correct?

Comment: @Botond I have no idea what the last sentence means.

Comment: I wanted to express that $T=f$ on $(-r, r)$. But for all $x$ in $(-R, R)$, we can find an $r$ so that $x<r<R$, which means that $T=f$ on $(-R,R)$.

Comment: From what you did, it follows that the equality $f(x)=T(x)$ holds on *some* interval $(-r,r)$ (assuming that $f$ is analytic), but I don't see how you jump from that to the assertion that the equality holds for every $x\in(-R,R)$.

Comment: I think I fixed it now. The $r \in (0, R)$ is only needed to get that $f^{(n)}(0)=n! a_n$.

Comment: How do you know that $\bigl(\forall x\in(-R,R)\bigr):f(x)=T(x)$?

Comment: In general, nothing guarantees that. But let $y \in (-R, R)$. Then we have that $f$ is defined at $y$ and $\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}}a_n y^n = f(y)$. Which means that $\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}}a_n y^n =T(y)$, so $T$ is convergent at $y$ and $T(y)=f(y)$ (because if $a_n=b_n \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$, then $a_n \to x \Leftrightarrow b_n \to x$)

Comment: How do you know that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_ny^n=f(y)$?

Comment: You are right, $R$ is the radius of convergence of the Taylor series, not of the series that defines $f$. Than you!